# How can I convert image from gallery to base64 in cordova

Tags: cordova, base64

I want to convert an image into Base64.

Use case: User chooses image from gallery and I want to send it to server to upload in base64 format. I used cordova camera and it successfully chose image from gallery. But problem is - unable to convert it to base64.

I've used `navigator.camera.getPicture`, and on success I get `content://media/external/images/media/18604` , which I've tried to convert to:

```css
var c=document.createElement('canvas');
             var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
             var img=new Image();
             img.onload = function(){
               c.width=this.width;
               c.height=this.height;
               //ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
             };
             img.src = imageData;
             var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Js code:

```css
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });

          function onPhotoURISuccess(imageData) {
            console.log("onPhotoURISuccess..")
           //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
           var image = imageData;
          //this is printing - content://media/external/images/media/18604
     console.log("Image..." + image);

        }

        function onFail(e){
            console.log("onFail..Err.." + e);
        }
}, false);
```

It doesn't seem to work, if I take a local jpeg, it works!

Comment: Could you post the js code that calls the `getPicture` method and its callbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `Camera.destinationType.DATA_URL` ?

The [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameragetpicturesuccesscallback-errorcallback-options) clearly explains how to call the `camera.getPicture` in order to have a base64 output (this code is from docs):

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 25,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

**Note**: please be aware that base64 operations are very memory intensive and could freeze the app especially in budget phones.

Comment: But when I print imageData , its showing - content://media/external/images/media/18604 instead of base64 string so server is throwing error - invalid format

Comment: Are you sure that you're passing right options to the method? If you're receiving the URI there is something wrong with parameters. See [the destination type doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameradestinationtype--enum) for more info.

Comment: @Smitha Suggest you to check out this specific section - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameradestinationtype--enum in official documentation. Try using DATA_URL option if you want base64 encoded string. If you use FILE_URI, you will get https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameradestinationtype--enum  Avoid using DATA_URL for large size pic as it is memory intensive

Comment: Thank you ! that helped much!